# PathGeometry in ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, uwp

In WPF I used to have my vector icons in ResourceDictionary like this:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="BackIconGeometry">M9.5,0 L16,0 8.75,7 22,7 22,11 8.75,11 16,18 9.5,18 0,9 z</PathGeometry>
```

and reference it from application like this:

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource BackIconGeometry}" Style="..." />
```

In UWP I'm getting error:

> A value of type 'String' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary
>   of type 'PathFigureCollection'

How can I store my icons data in resource dictionaries? I would like to avoid storing them as `<Style TargetType="Path" />` since I would like to use different styles for the icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Path is an actual string value that is used for Binding so instead of using `PathGeometry` use `x:String` in resource Dictionary.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="BackIconGeometry">M9.5,0 L16,0 8.75,7 22,7 22,11 8.75,11 16,18 9.5,18 0,9 z</x:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

and in XAML you can use like below.

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource BackIconGeometry}" />
```

Comment: Oh, I've tried this before I asked, but I forgot to include the resource dictionary. My bad...